# Is targetEntity attribute necessary when mapping the inverse relationship with @OneToOne?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In this [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html) the author maps `Invoice` entity to the `Order` entity as follows:

```
   @OneToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
   mappedBy="order",targetEntity=Invoice.class)
   private Invoice invoice;
```

Is the targetEntity attribute necessary in this case or will the Hibernate persistence manager derive it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#targetEntity()

Comment: The field specifies it! you don't have to duplicate basic things and almost never have to use that attribute